# ASP.Net Model to Javascript - Passing Data from server to client

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hey guys quick question what is the best approach on converting Model to Javascript.

I tried using this

```
@{ 
    var arr = new string[3];
    arr[0] = "1";
    arr[1] = "2";
    arr[2] = "3"; 
    var jason = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);

}
<script type="text/javascript">   
    var string = '@jason';
    var variable2 = jQuery.parseJSON(string);
    alert(variable2.Id);
</script>
```

as you can guess it did not work, I look through the sample of jQuery which should work but I am not sure if it is compatible with JsonConvert of .net

Its my first time on programming in the client side so this is quite a simple question but I tried looking the answer from the net. Mostly I see are uber complicated answers and at least 3 and higher old so I am guessing there should be an easier way to do this now?

Comment: at the execution time of this line `var string = '@jason'` , this `var jason = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);` might not be executed

Comment: `var myModel = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');`

Comment: use this `var string = @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)`

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this needs an answer because it's the number 2 result from google and has been viewed over 200 times, and as stated by the OP every other answer is generally long and/or convoluted. But the simplest answer is:

Javascript added to your aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myObject = <%=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyNetObject)%>;
</script>
```

The key bit being that your output of HTML looks as follows:

```
<script type="test/javascript">
   var myObject = {"Prop1":"value1","Prop2":"Value2"};
</script>
```

Javascript natively handle JSON so you don't need to reparse anything on the client side. If the object is properly serialized it will be recognized without further conversion (this includes lists and object properties).

In the example provided in the OP the resultant Javascript object would be a simple array. So access to the elements on the client side would be:

```
alert(variable2[0]), alert(variable2[1]), alert(variable2[2])....
```

In order to provide the Javascript property calling functionality that OP is trying to do on the client side would require the following on the server side:

```
var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(new { ID1 = 1, ID2 = 2, ID3 = 3 });
```

In which an object with Named properties is serialized into the page.